# Why does std::endl makes this loop run forever?

Tags: c++, infinite-loop, endl

I found this code on a q&a platform.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
std::cout << i << " " << i * 12345678 << std::endl;
}
```

At first sight, this seems normal but  instead it runs infinitely.
Results at : https://ideone.com/7F88MV

Now I changed the std::endl to "\n" and it behaved normal this time running for 300 times, terminating at i=299.

So what is going on with the std::endl keyword ?

Comment: The program causes undefined behaviour due to signed integer overflow, which means anything can happen

Comment: Okay.. I got your point. I changed int to long long int and got normal results. But if it happend due to signed integer overflow then, why doesn't it happen in cases where I use int but do not put std::endl at the end ? In those cases the loop terminates as normal.

Comment: hard to say really, the language is only defined for valid programs and this isn't one